# TypeError: data.slice is not a function Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am working with a JSON file with topic modeling data:

## JSON

```
[{"message": "Cygnus olor is a large bird with a majestic white coat, brazingly orange beak and a black knob on their bill that is larger in males." , 
"messageTopic": 0, 
"contributionPercent": 0.9901618361473083},
{"message": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 
"messageTopic": 1, 
"contributionPercent": 0.981721043586731}]
```

I am trying to display this information in an Angular material table.

## Typescript

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TopicDocumentDatum } from './topic-document-table-types';

@Component({
  selector: 'amm-topic-document-table',
  templateUrl: './topic-document-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topic-document-table.component.scss']
})
export class TopicDocumentTableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<TopicDocumentDatum>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'messageTopic',
    'message',
    'contributionPercent'
  ];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(
      (data: TopicDocumentDatum[]) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        console.log(data); // just to see if the data is being passed through
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

}
```

## HTML

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="15px" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div id="topics-document-table" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="messageTopic">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Topic </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.messageTopic}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="message">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Text </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.message}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="contributionPercent">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Contribution Percent </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.contributionPercent}} </td>
            </ng-container>
            
        </table>
        <mat-paginator class="mat-paginator-sticky" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run this, I get an error: `ERROR TypeError: data.slice is not a function` printed in the console and the reference is to my typescript code `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator`. I've checked to ensure that the data being passed in is an array, the console output is: `Object { topicDocumentTableData: (200) [...] }`. When I expand this, the array that I passed in appears, so I believe that the data is being passed in correctly. So, I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is great appreciated!

Comment: If you wrap your table in an ngIf to make sure dataSource is set does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MatTableDataSource accepts an array not an object.

You have to set:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data.topicDocumentTableData);
```

Comment: This appears to get rid of the problem, but my TS is throwing errors `Property 'topicDocumentTableData' does not exist on type 'TopicDocumentDatum[]'`

Comment: yea because in`subscribe( (data: TopicDocumentDatum[])` data is not of type `TopicDocumentDatum[]`. Declare it as `(data: any)`

Comment: Perfect thanks. I can eliminate the need for `any` by: 

`ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.data.subscribe(
      (data: {topicDocumentTableData: TopicDocumentDatum[]}) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        console.log(data); // just to see if the data is being passed through
      });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using JSON like this
        `
        {
            "data": [
                {
                  "id": 01,
                  "name1": "some name",
                  "country": {
                    "name": "country name",
                    "code": "xyz"
              },
              "course": "some course"
                },
                {
                  "id": 02,
                  "name1": "some name",
                  "country": {
                    "name": "country name",
                    "code": "xyz"
                  },
                  "course": "some course"
                }
            ]
        }
        `
        
The simples solution would be to remove the "data" block and pass the JSON as an array of object like this
    `
         [
                {
                  "id": 01,
                  "name1": "some name",
                  "country": {
                    "name": "country name",
                    "code": "xyz"
                  },
                  "course": "some course"
                },
                {
                  "id": 01,
                  "name1": "some name",
                  "country": {
                    "name": "country name",
                    "code": "xyz"
                  },
                  "course": "some course"
                }
            ]
        '
```